# PHP: Removing excess linebreaks from a string

Tags: php, replace

I have some database entries with some badly formatted html. I would like to clean up this in the following way:

1. remove any blank lines.
2. remove all linebreaking tags from end of string (`<br>` and `<br />`)
3. remove any variation of br tag if it follows a `</p>` even if its on the next line.

Im fairly good with regular expressions, but really bad when it comes to regular replacing, so I would need some input of how to do this in a good way.

See example string below:

```
<br>
<br>



<br>
<br>
<p>Highburys torsdagsquiz handler om
&aring; kunne litt om det meste, og litt flaks.</p>
<br>
<p>Juks og bruk av hjelpemidler er strengt forbudt , og
medf&oslash;rer diskvalifikasjon og van&aelig;re.</p>
<br>
<p>Hvert lag kan stille med inntil 5 deltagere, alle kan delta og
kommer du alene er det alltid et lag som kan ha bruk for deg. Det
er ingen forh&aring;ndsp&aring;melding.</p>
<br>
<p>Det stilles 50 sp&oslash;rsm&aring;l fordelt p&aring; 2 omganger
om alt mellom himmel og jord. Vinnerlaget f&aring;r en flott
premie!</p>
<br>
<p>Moroa starter kl. 19.00. Det kan bli trangt om plassene,
s&aring; det er en god ide og v&aelig;re tidlig ute.</p>
<br>
<p>Lykke til, vi sees!</p>
<br/>
<br>


<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

The wanted output should be something like this:

```
<p>Highburys torsdagsquiz handler om
&aring; kunne litt om det meste, og litt flaks.</p>
<p>Juks og bruk av hjelpemidler er strengt forbudt , og
medf&oslash;rer diskvalifikasjon og van&aelig;re.</p>
<p>Hvert lag kan stille med inntil 5 deltagere, alle kan delta og
kommer du alene er det alltid et lag som kan ha bruk for deg. Det
er ingen forh&aring;ndsp&aring;melding.</p>
<p>Det stilles 50 sp&oslash;rsm&aring;l fordelt p&aring; 2 omganger
om alt mellom himmel og jord. Vinnerlaget f&aring;r en flott
premie!</p>
<p>Moroa starter kl. 19.00. Det kan bli trangt om plassene,
s&aring; det er en god ide og v&aelig;re tidlig ute.</p>
<p>Lykke til, vi sees!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

it may be helpful:

```
function cleanText($string) {
   $str = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $string);  // OR $str = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $string));
   $str = strip_tags($str, '<p>');
   return $str;
}

echo cleanText($string);
```